# How can I store my Microsoft SQL Database_Diagram inside SSDT project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using microsoft SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), in my projects to try to keep everything in order. 
I was wondering if anyone know how to store the Database Diagram into SSDT Project, in order to don't lose any work and keep this model updated with my team?

I tryed to compare it using schema, but it didn't exists. 
I also couldn't find any Database Diagram in Visual studio 2013.

Am I wrong to try to use this model type? Are there better ways to do it?
Also, Is it possible to create Jobs throught SSDT?

[image]

[image]

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 3):

The database diagrams are stored in internal tables so you could add their definitions and include the data in a post deploy script *but* you would end up deploying to all your environments which is unusual (I don't know your circumstance so I won't say wrong!).

Unless you particularly needed the diagrams in ssms I would look to something else, redgate have a database diagramming tool, I prefer to keep a copy of Visio 2010 pro to generate them, the vsd files can then be added to the project and shared between the team.

I assume it is to help document your databases but If you wanted the editing and designer support from diagrams you get that other ways with ssdt.

Re: jobs, there is no native object but you can create them in pre/post deploy scripts.

Comment: I'm currently exploring SSDT, then I would like to know a little more of what it can do. You said that I could get editing and designer support from diagrams with ssdt? How can I do that?

Comment: Hey! not with diagrams specifically but if you create a table and open it you get a designer etc.